# instr versus regex for string match in oracle

Tags: regex, oracle

I am using the below to get the top count of pages visited in past 60 days, where I need a match in the url for 'abc.cfm' or '/entity/'. Is there a way to do this using regex? Is the below method ok to use or is there a better way. Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT url, count(URL)
  FROM tableone
  WHERE ( INSTR(url, 'abc.cfm') > 0 
   or  
         INSTR(url, '/entity/') > 0 )
and VIEW_DT > sysdate - 60
group by URL
order by count(URL)  desc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `like`. This will usually be a bit faster than `instr` and **much** faster than `regexp_like`:

```
 WHERE (  url like '%abc.cfm%'
       or url like  '%/entity/%'
       )
```

I tested on a table with 1.8M rows of which 700 matched the criteria.  The approximate timings from repeated tests were:

```
instr         0.9 seconds
regexp_like  15.0 seconds
like          0.6 seconds
```

I would only use `regexp_like` for expressions that are too complex for `like`.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
regexp_like(url,'(abc.cfm|/entity/)')
```

instead of

```
( INSTR(url, 'abc.cfm') > 0 
   or  
         INSTR(url, '/entity/') > 0 )
```